# How to create custom default install folder in WIX?

Tags: xml, wix

I need to create a custom **default** install folder, like 
`D:\My Company\My Program\`. How to make it in WiX? I need to be sure that it`s disk D. Are it`s posible?

Comment: refer this link : http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html

Comment: @MohammadAli I don\`t  need "ProgramFilesFolder" I need my custom Path.

Comment: What is this for? An IIS install? Is this installer going to target any system, or is it for your own use only? What happens on a system without a D:\ drive? Did you test?

Comment: Instead of changing the default from a well-known symbolic path that resolves to the actual path that the user's computer is set up to use for program files to a potentially non-existent path, perhaps you and the administrator running this setup know enough to pass all the properties needed for a non-interactive installation (and might even prefer to do it remotely).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I find a answer.
First of all to change folder use

```
<Property Id="ROOTDRIVE">
  <![CDATA[D:\]]>
</Property>
```

and install folder will be like

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="MYSUPERCOMPANY">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MYSUPERPRODUCT">
      <Directory Id="Files" Name="Files" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: So what happens when you try to install on a machine that doesn't have a d:?   Crash

Comment: you need to check if D: is there. unless you don't check that, the answer is useless

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to write a custom action that sets INSTALLFOLDER to D:\ if D:\ exists and  INSTALLFOLDER doesn't already have a value and the product isn't already installed.